# Count parent nodes which have 2 types of child nodes - specifically 1 "boy" node and 1 "girl" node each

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, siblings

I have XML files containing data like this...

```
    <parent>
        <boy/>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <girl/>
    <parent>
    <parent>
        <boy/>
        <girl/>
    </parent>
```

...and I want to count the parents who have both types of child nodes IE: 1 boy and 1 girl each. In the above example the answer is 1 as only 1 parent has both a boy and a girl. I'm using xpath to query the XML. What I currently have is something like this...

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load(inXML);
 int ParentsWithBothKids = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("MY QUERY HERE!!!").Count;
```

The various queries I try either throw an error as being invalid xpath or always return 0 even though the small test XML file I'm using definitely has some.

Any ideas as to what xpath query I can use?

Comment: And what are "the various queries I try" ?

Comment: At least 1 boy and 1 girl or 1 or more boys and 1 or more girls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `parent[boy and girl]` as your xpath query.

Check out [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I did try this previously and it didn't work but on your recommendation I tried again (and I also played about with the MSDN examples you linked too) and then I noticed it... The XML is a slightly different structure than I thought it was! Doh! So I tweeked the Xpath query a bit and it worked. Thanks for your help - it was a very useful sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
count(//parent[boy and girl])
```

When this XPath expression is evaluated, the result is the count of all `parent` elements in the XML document, such that each of them has a `boy` and a `girl` child.

To evaluate such an XPath expression (not selecting nodes), use `XPathNavigator.Evaluate()`